# Will they stop treating Sasuke as the main character in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

So I have been watching Naruto for 1 week and am on ep 60. But what I have noticed is that they show Sasuke as if he is the main charachter a lot of time and sometimes even more than they show Naruto...will this continue? I mean, Naruto is the main character so they should only treat **him** as the main character. Else the show should have been Named "Nauto and Sasuke".

Will they keep giving this much emphasis on Sasuke, or will this thing slowly fade away. As of now, almost everyone is thinking about him and how great he is and its like nobody cares about Naruto.

Comment: they do , they show goes mostly naruto after some time

Comment: The main characters of Naruto are Naruto, Sasuke, Sakura, and Kakashi, but the protagonist is Naruto. Technically where you are in the anime, Naruto is a nobody. He then later turns into a hero and gets all the attention.

Comment: Would you please consider that you have 500+ more episodes to go, so try watching those and you will have a whole other opinion

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for focusing so much on Sasuke is because he will later effect Narutos life so much so you have to know him enough to understand the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Author Kishimoto Masashi is clever to introduce Sasuke in his epic manga "Naruto". If you look at any famous books or mangas, there will always we two characters who compete each other. 
For example, consider Dragon Ball Z, you have Goku & Vegeta, if you take Bleach there is Ichigo & Uryu, If you see Pokemon there is Ash & Gary etc.
There will always be an eternal rival for every super hero. I'm not talking about super villain.
With these characters, the authors show competency between the main lead & the second lead just as in real life :)
I could go on, but I think I made my point.